# How to package Spring Boot web application with maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

[my web application structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUeSM.png)

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>tally</artifactId>
    <groupId>win.bestyyt</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>win.bestyyt</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                <configurationDirectory>conf</configurationDirectory>
                <configurationSourceDirectory>src/main/resources</configurationSourceDirectory>
                <copyConfigurationDirectory>true</copyConfigurationDirectory>
                <includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>true</includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>
                <assembleDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tally</assembleDirectory>
                <extraJvmArguments>-Xms256m</extraJvmArguments>
                <binFileExtensions>
                    <unix>.sh</unix>
                </binFileExtensions>
                <platforms>
                    <platform>windows</platform>
                    <platform>unix</platform>
                </platforms>
                <repositoryName>lib</repositoryName>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>win.bestyyt.web.Application</mainClass>
                        <name>start</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

After I ran the package command, I got directory structure like below, it's flat.

[structure after package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBQFJ.png)

And I found all the resources still in "web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
[jar structure(sorry for the resolution)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT6SS.png)

while I executing the start.bat, it keep restarting.

[restarting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoLXz.png)

My question is :

1, how  to get the hierarchical resource directory?

2, how to make the program run correctly? (do not keep restarting)

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged this [assembly], but this obviously has nothing to do with assembly-language CPU instructions.  Totally guessing at changing it to [tag:java-bytecode-asm] instead of just removing it.

Comment: You cannot and shouldn't do that. Use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` which is designed and build for this. Spring Boot expects the executable jar to be in a certain format that isn't going to happen when you use another maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [spring boot maven plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) instead? Spring made their own plugin to avoid having to use assembly or other related plugins.

It also looks like Spring is trying to close your datasource twice. Try adding this to your java config:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
public DataSource dataSource()
```

Comment: it's not very good to use spring boot maven plugin, the size of the fat jar is a little big. 
After adding the destroyMethod to dataSource, no more error print, but still keep restarting